# How to run tkinter function with both a key bind and a button command?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

Is it possible to run a function with both a button press and an event? When I try to run this function by pressing the button, it, understandably, gives an error

> TypeError: listFiller() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'.

Couldn't find a similar problem, but maybe that is just my lack of programming knowledge.

Code:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.myButton = tk.Button(master, text='ok', command=self.listFiller)
        self.myButton.pack()

        self.myEntry = tk.Entry(master)
        self.myEntry.bind("<Return>",self.listFiller)
        self.myEntry.pack()

    def listFiller(self, event):
        data = self.myEntry.get()
        print(data)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting `event=None` for the function and then passing event from the `bind` only, like:

```py
self.myButton = tk.Button(master, text='ok', command=self.listFiller)
.....

self.myEntry.bind("<Return>", lambda e: self.listFiller()) # Same as lambda e: self.listFiller(e)

def listFiller(self, event=None):
    data = self.myEntry.get()
```

This way, when you press the button, `event` is taken as `None`. But when `bind` is triggered(i.e.,<kbd>Enter</kbd> is hit), `event` is passed on implicitly(works even if you pass it explicitly) as `e`.

So after you have understood how this works behind the hood, now even if you remove `lambda`, `e` would still get passed as `event` as it happens implicitly.

```
self.myEntry.bind("<Return>",self.listFiller) # As mentioned by Lafexlos
```

---

Though keep in mind, when you press a tkinter button, you cannot use any attributes from `event`, like `event.keysym` or anything, but it would work if you use <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: I don't think you need lambda in the `bind`. you can directly use `self.myEntry.bind("<Return>", self.listFiller)` and that should pass `event` parameter automatically.

Comment: @Lafexlos Yes, that is true too. I wanted to show the working behind it. Ill add that in. Thanks for mentioning it.