# Issue of scope when getting data from an entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, scope

I am making a login and register screen using tkinter. I have a function to make the login and register screen (**named form**), and this is where the entry widgets are located (**login_username and login_password**).

Now, if I try to access this data outside the function, I get a NameError which I know is a problem to do with scope.

***I do not want to use a global variable***, as this is bad practice, but is there any other way solve this without majorly changing the code? Many Thanks :D

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

def form(master, label_1_text, label_2_text, button_text, commands):

    label_hidden_1=Label(master,text="").pack()
    label_hidden=Label(master, text="").pack()

    new_username_label=Label(master,text=label_1_text,font=('arial', 10, 'bold')).pack()
    login_username=Entry(master, width=40).pack()
    label_hidden_2=Label(master,text="").pack()

    new_password_label=Label(master,text=label_2_text,font=('arial', 10, 'bold')).pack()
    login_password=Entry(master,width=40, show='*')
    login_password.pack()
    login_password.bind('<Return>', lambda e: commands())
    label_hidden_3=Label(master,text="").pack()

    login_btn=Button(master,text=button_text,width=20,height=1,font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), command=commands).pack()

    master.mainloop()

def main():
    
    def login_user(*args, e=None):
        print(login_password.get()) # This is where i get and scope error (NameError)

    def register_user(*args, e=None):
        print(login_password.get()) # And here also

    window = Tk()
    window.title('Registration')
    window.geometry('275x300')

    form(window, 'NEW USERNAME', 'NEW PASSWORD', 'REGISTER', register_user)

    window = Tk()
    window.title('Login')
    window.geometry('275x300')
    
    form(window, 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', 'LOGIN', login_user)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I stated i do not want to do this as it is bad practice

Comment: As @ Sujay pointed out, `login_password` only exists in your `form` function, so you need to tell python to make the variable global by using `global login_password` at the start of your `top` function

Comment: Global var's are usually refer to bad practice, however they are sometimes necessary. A large issue is that you are declaring a variable that you want to persist inside a function. This is fine as long as the variable already exists or if you return the value.

Comment: The only problem with global variables is that you can get variable name clashes if you aren't careful. The best way of approaching this problem would be by using classes.

Comment: @TheLizzard how could I do this using classes?

Comment: There are plenty of examples using classes with tkinter

Comment: @PythonCodingTutorials Do you know how to use classes? If not, look at *object oriented programming* tutorials. It's too much to explain in a stackoverflow answer. Also it might mean that you need to redesign your code. The advantage is that you aren't going to need any global variables.

Comment: Check: [How to make 2 functions for 2 tkinter windows more condensed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68124161/13382000)

Answer (score 0):

After the reading the comments, I have decided to use classes as TheLizzard and Cool Cloud mentioned. Thanks for the info.